# Embedding Bokeh server into Flask app while retaining plot size

Tags: python, google-chrome, flask, bokeh

I found an example in the Bokeh github of a Flask app that embeds a Bokeh server [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/branch-3.4/examples/server/api/flask_embed.py). When I run it and open the Flask URL in Google Chrome, I see the embedded plot. When I directly open the Bokeh URL in my Google Chrome, I also see the plot. However, the two plots are of different size. Below are two screenshots of the same size that illustrate this.

The first one is the direct Bokeh plot, and represents the correct size. The second one is the embedded plot and is too small. **How do I fix the example so that the embedded plot size matches the standalone plot size?**

I should note that in Firefox, the plots appear to be the same size.

[image: Standalone Bokeh]
[image: Embedded Bokeh]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the bokeh plot is embedded in a template and they also use a `theme.yaml` file to control the plot size.

In the example, the template is loaded here:

```py
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def bkapp_page():
    script = server_document('http://localhost:5006/bkapp')
    return render_template("embed.html", script=script, template="Flask")
```

and you can see the template [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/branch-3.4/examples/server/api/templates/embed.html).

The `theme.yaml` file appears to provide width/height control for the plot, referenced here in the Flask server code:

```
    doc.theme = Theme(filename="theme.yaml")
```

see [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/branch-3.4/examples/server/api/theme.yaml) for the contents of `theme.yaml`.

Are you using the same `theme.yaml` and `embed.html` template? If you change the width and height in the `theme.yaml` does your plot change size in the Flask app?

Comment: I am using the example pretty much exactly as-is. The only change I made is to add to `localhost:5006` to the `allow_websocket_origin=` argument when constructing the bokeh `Server`, so that I could access the server directly through the browser. Doubling a dimension in the `theme.yaml` doubles it in the displayed figure in both Flask and Bokeh pages. But the difference between the two persists.

Comment: FWIW, I realized that it is only in Google Chrome that the difference exists. When I use Firefox, the two look identical.

Comment: That's curious - there must be some difference between the two... I'm at a loss for what it might be. My only guess was that the example was partially copied and maybe left out the `theme.yaml`. The only other thing I can think of is you've accidentally got a zoom setting on one browser but not the other, but that's a stretch.

Comment: Possibly some things to look into here, not exactly the same issue, but might be related: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/10120

Comment: If I get some time later I'll see if I can reproduce on my system.

Comment: The tip in that link to look at `window.devicePixelRatio` helped me discover the issue. I was accessing the Flask page via `127.0.01` and the Bokeh page via `localhost`, and I had a 75% zoom in my browser for the `localhost` domain. Pressing Ctrl+0 undid the zoom. Accepting your answer thanks to the link you provided!

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it resolved. Was curious to know what the issue was.